# Run different tasks using multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I'm writing a code in python that suppose to get all links that was founded in one url save them as key:value pairs (url:[links]) & then go over those links and do the same thing over & over until I got enough keys.

I've already done this with a list of threads and removing them from the list when they were done running but i want to use thread pool for easy maintenance

To do this i make 2 functions:

1. get the content from the url and return it
2. extract the links from the content and return them

Now I want to mange those tasks with thread pool but i don't know how to do it properly because i don't know how to control the flow.
I can extract the links only after the get request returned the html page.

these are the functions I will use:

```py
def extract_links(response):
    arr_starts = [m.start() for m in re.finditer('href="https://', response.content)]
    arr_ends = []
    links = []
    for start in arr_starts:
        end_index = response.content.find('"', start + 6)
        arr_ends.append(end_index)
    for i in range(len(arr_starts)):
        link = response.content[arr_starts[i] + 6:arr_ends[i]]
        links.append(link)


def get_page(url):
    return requests.get(url)
```

and this is the code i did it the first time:

```py
first_url = r'https://blablabla'
    hash_links = {}
    thread_list = []
    web_crawl(first_url, hash_links)
    while len(hash_links.keys()) < 30:
        if len(thread_list) < MAX_THREAD_COUNT:
            for urls in hash_links.values():
                for url in urls:
                    if url not in hash_links:
                        new_tread = threading.Thread(target=web_crawl, args=(url, hash_links))
                        thread_list.append(new_tread)
                        new_tread.start()
                        new_tread.join()
        else:
            for t in thread_list:
                if not t.isAlive():
                    t.handled = True
            thread_list = [t for t in thread_list if not t.handled]
    for key in hash_links.keys():
        print key + ':'
        for link in hash_links[key]:
            print '----' + link
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that of producing content from a URL and then processing the links found in that URL as keys, also scheduling those links for processing, but do that in parallel using the thread pool and semaphore objects.

If that is the case, I would point you to [this article](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Synchronization_Semaphore_Objects_Thread_Pool.php) for semaphore objects and the thread pool.

Also, your problem sounds to me a lot like something that would benefit from a producer-consumer architecture, so I would also recommend [this article](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Synchronization_Producer_Consumer_using_Queue.php).